# After unlock iPhone application must be active in background

Tags: iphone, launch, unlock

In my application I want that my application being active even after termination of application. I want that when "slide to unlock" my appliaction is launched.

It is possible? How can I do it without jailbreaking & all...

It is a convenience feature for the user. The application is an audio player and should start playing music immediately when the user unlocks his iPhone or speaking a text "Welcome to iPhone" or something like that.

Comment: I have surly a good reason there are many apps which plays audio in background.Because it will be active in background then, when it slide to unlock there will be launch of application which is active.So launched that application default so i want that

Comment: OK. You mean it's a convenience feature for the user. The player starts playing music immediately when the user unlocks his iPhone, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: YES,Now you understand me correctly,take a example you slide to unlock  and listen a sound like "Welcome to iphone" & something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify more about it that what you want to do. For this you might be use jail broken tools. 
Use this link

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-unlock-any-jailbroken-iphone-on-any-baseband-and-firmware/

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-unlock-any-jailbroken-iphone-on-any-baseband-and-firmware/

Comment: Exactly it is for jaibroken app in which i required to open lock screen when "device slide to unlock" event.

Comment: @chandan, this answer is not detailed enough. Please write a summary here how to proceed.